# How does an interface inherit another interface,but not include its types of indexers?

Tags: typescript

Observe the following example. I don't want types of indexers`[x: string]: any` to be inherited.

> `interface A` cannot be disassembled because it is from a library actually

```
interface A {
  [x: string]: any
  foo: string
  bar?: number
}

interface B extends A {
  baz?: boolean
}

// He should report an error. An attribute named qux is not allowed
const o: B = {
  foo: 'foo',
  qux: 'qux',
}
```

I hope the type of `o` is

```
{
  foo: string
  bar?: number
  baz?: boolean
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously the recommended approach is to rewrite `A` so that both `A` and `B` inherit from a base type without an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures).  But you can't do that, you'll need to use an `Omit`-like type.

I say "like" because the [`Omit<T, K>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys) doesn't work to remove string index signatures.  If you try `Omit<T, string>` it will end up removing all `string`-assignable keys, which is usually all of them.

Instead you could use [key remapping via `as`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) to specifically target the key of type `string` and not any string [literal](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) keys:

```
type OmitStringIndex<T> = {
    [K in keyof T as string extends K ? never : K]: T[K]
}
```

You can verify that this works on `A`:

```
type BaseA = OmitStringIndex<A>;
/* type BaseA = {
  foo: string;
  bar?: number;
} */
```

And then have `B` extend `OmitStringIndex<A>` instead of `A`:

```
interface B extends OmitStringIndex<A> {
    baz?: boolean
}

const o: B = {
    foo: 'foo',
    qux: 'qux', // error, excess property on object literal
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?useDefineForClassFields=true&target=9&noErrorTruncation=true#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAUIUsUgC4CeMyA8mAJakDKpATncAOYCSwAJhAA8APABUAfEgC8efCTlIA2gGkk7JAGsI5APYAzJCKQgoSKK3Yckg0hD4mVAfiTAIANwgskALiRKAuj4iyn6yJAC+RCTsNiy6CMgAgjLyJAoCPmZsnAFGwOShKbra2hnmnAXyAEYgLA4+wACuYJUeFREVFFRIAELGEEnStAzMWdx8gkIJYgDcFQD0AFRklMi9UP1SyfJFJaZlHLMp1bX1TS0sh+FIC3ORxNEecYg9VgI2dkhDTPs8-MJTWyOICwdSQlWKGAgIGAbTuSHg2mAZiQu26mwIKWIOx8AHIdjiADQVOQARwa6SQOLJAkJSDmcysLBY2hYBNeiCgJhgzKoLAoKOAKMqACsIPBSEgMAwPJhYWEgA)

Comment: You beat me again by 2 min! https://tsplay.dev/Wo8Gaw